# Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety" error while running flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error while trying to run my flutter application:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWmGy.png)

I started getting this error after running the

```
flutter pub outdated
```

command and then the

```
flutter pub upgrade outdated_package
```

command. But I don't know if this is related to the error in any way.

I have tried adding `--no-sound-null-safety` to flutter run additional args in VScode.
I can't run the app anywhere so I'm stuck with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have installed Flutter 3.10 with dart 3.0, and had that option left over in your IDE settings.  That might also mean you have Dart code that isn't null-safe yet, and meant to run with a dart before dart 2.12.

First, remove that flag.  See if anything breaks.  If nothing, you're done.
If you find you have some code that needs to be migrated, you'll need to install flutter 3.7 and the dart 2 included with it.

I highly recommend you use [puro](https://puro.dev/) to have the current Flutter installed alongside the legacy flutter, switchable per-project.  (Puro is like FVM, but a heckuva lot better.)  You can then use the legacy flutter to first migrate your code to dart 2.12, update your pubspec, and then you should be able to run it under dart 3 again.

Comment: I removed it and now it's fine. Thanks for the help!